# Use or not Keep-alive in soap ESB request

Tags: web-services, soap, esb, keep-alive

What is the best approach to HTTP SOAP request from the ESB system to WebService, is use or not keep-alive?

Answer (score 0):

The rational of using HTTP keep alive is that using the same TCP connection to send and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses (otherwise we have to open a new connection for every single request/response pair. Hence using persistent connections is very important for improving HTTP performance.

And we should keep in mind that SOAP and HTTP-Keep alive is two orthogonal things. But, when we thing about web service performances, yes, using keep alive is much better.